# Scanf() won't read in the integer

Tags: objective-c

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    NSString *str; 
    int key = 0;

    printf("\nEnter a string: ");
    scanf("%@", &str);
    printf("\nEnter a key (It must be any number from 1 - 25): ");
    scanf("%d", &key);


    return 0;
}
```

It just skips the line `scanf("%d", key);` and ends the program after that. I've seen other problems with scanf() similar to this, but couldn't find an answer that would fit this program. So how do I stop it from skipping this line?

NOTE: This is Objective C on Windows 7 using Notepad++

Comment: What happens if you try this: `int r = scanf("%d", &key); printf("%d\n", r);`? Does zero get printed?

Comment: If zero gets printed, try adding space in front of `%d`, like this: `int r = scanf(" %d", &key);` and see if it changes anything.

Comment: I got it to work now

Comment: Did you use a loop or added a space in front of `%d` to get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add the following code before the second scanf:

```
while (getchar() != '\n');
```

The problem is that there is still whitespace in the stdin buffer which makes your program 'ignore' the second scanf. You could also use `fflush(stdin)` (in most cases on Windows it solves the problem), but this is actually undefined behaviour and therefore not best practice.

This is common C (nothing objective-C specific) behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of the scanf you are using before! ie

```
scanf("%@", &str);
```

What happens in this case is that, the console takes an input string from user till the user hits enter key. But the enter key pressed by the user gets saved in the buffer(ie '\n').And when next scanf(the one in which you are trying to input an integer) gets executed,it looks in the buffer,as there is '\n' already stored,the scanf never takes any further input from the user as it has already received '\n' ie termination character